# Laravel : Syntax error or access violation: tickets.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *,

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, model

```
public function ScopeDistance($query, $from_latitude, $from_longitude, $distance)
{
    $raw = DB::raw('ROUND ( ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(' . $from_latitude . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $from_longitude . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $from_latitude . ') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) ) AS distance');
    return $query->select('*')->addSelect($raw)->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')->groupBy('distance')->having('distance', '<=', $distance);
}
```

I am trying to find the nearest data from latitude and longitude. I get this error? Is the solution wrong?

```
       $userData = UserLocation::whereUserId(3)->first();
    $max_distance = 50;
    $nearByTickets = Ticket::with(['brand', 'appliance'])->distance($userData->lat, $userData->lng, $max_distance)->get();
    return success($nearByTickets, __('tickets neared to you is'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

So your code need to be updated as below. using a php array as second param for `DB::raw` method

```php
    public function ScopeDistance($query, $from_latitude, $from_longitude, $distance)
    {
        return
            DB::select(DB::raw('Select ROUND ( ( 6371 
            * acos( cos( radians(:from_latitude1) ) 
            * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
            * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(:from_latitude2) )
            + sin( radians(:from_longitude) ) 
            * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) ) AS distance 
            From tickets
            group by distance 
            having distance <= :distance
            order by distance ASC', array(
                'from_latitude1' => $from_latitude,
                'from_latitude2' => $from_latitude,
                'from_longitude' => $from_longitude,
                'distance' => $distance
            )));
    }
```

Comment: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters It gives me this error @MarvenSank

Comment: I would suggest you to use full raw query inside DB::select including `$distance` . Check updated answer.

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by distance\n        having distance <= ? from `tickets`' at line 7 ?

Comment: `order by` should come at the end.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `tickets`'  Its still says thisss

Comment: what is tickets ? `$query` is a instance of tickets ? 
try running your query on my sql and replace parameters. I have updated the answer